# Selected tab background color (ActionBarSherlock)

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I have three tabs (ActionBarSherlock) and by default there is a small indicator which is blue. What I want is to change so that the selected tab is red, i.e. not only the indicator but the whole tab.

Is that possible? I have tried some suggested solutions without luck.

Comment: Show us what 'you have tried' ?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12346952/1906361

Comment: I tried the example in the link above and after some customization it works :) Thanks Shumail